# how can i get this code to choose a random word once from each array to print a sentence?

Tags: java, arrays, random, printing

Here is my code so far, how do I get this to work though as I am struggling to print a sentence at all, let alone randomly.

I need one word from each array to print a sentence using the words in the array

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MadLibs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] nouns = null;
        String[] verbs = null;
        String[] adjec = null;
        String[] adver = null; 

        nouns[0] = "Lion";
        nouns[1] = "Stewart";
        nouns[2] = "Timbaktu";
        nouns[3] = "Kilamanjaro";
        nouns[4] = "Hawai";
        nouns[5] = "Frog";
        nouns[6] = "Russia";
        nouns[7] = "Dimethyltryptaline";
        nouns[8] = "Dog";
        nouns[9] = "Badness";

        verbs[0] = "hear";
        verbs[1] = "achieve";
        verbs[2] = "smash";
        verbs[3] = "destroy";                   
        verbs[4] = "smoke";
        verbs[5] = "burn";
        verbs[6] = "rose";
        verbs[7] = "speak";
        verbs[8] = "type";
        verbs[9] = "be";

        adjec[0] = "Tangy";
        adjec[1] = "Sour";
        adjec[2] = "Smooth";
        adjec[3] = "Sticky";
        adjec[4] = "Soft";
        adjec[5] = "Black";
        adjec[6] = "Whispering";
        adjec[7] = "Resonant";
        adjec[8] = "Wide";
        adjec[9] = "Long";

        adver[0] = "Truthfully";
        adver[1] = "Endlessly";
        adver[2] = "Painfully";
        adver[3] = "Tirelessly";
        adver[4] = "Beautifully";
        adver[5] = "Uneasily";
        adver[6] = "Wickedly";
        adver[7] = "Briskly";
        adver[8] = "Now";
        adver[9] = "Last";


        String random = (verbs[new Random().nextInt(verbs.length)]);


        System.out.println("Does your" + verbs + " your " + adjec + nouns + adver );


    }

}
```

Comment: `Math.random` or `Random`

Comment: You should initialize arrays first - `String[] nouns = new String[10];`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go :) Hope this is what you want (I wouldn't normally solve a school assignment but sometimes you just feel like it):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] nouns = new String[10];
    String[] verbs = new String[10];
    String[] adjec = new String[10];
    String[] adver = new String[10]; 

    nouns[0] = "Lion";
    nouns[1] = "Stewart";
    nouns[2] = "Timbaktu";
    nouns[3] = "Kilamanjaro";
    nouns[4] = "Hawai";
    nouns[5] = "Frog";
    nouns[6] = "Russia";
    nouns[7] = "Dimethyltryptaline";
    nouns[8] = "Dog";
    nouns[9] = "Badness";

    verbs[0] = "hear";
    verbs[1] = "achieve";
    verbs[2] = "smash";
    verbs[3] = "destroy";                   
    verbs[4] = "smoke";
    verbs[5] = "burn";
    verbs[6] = "rose";
    verbs[7] = "speak";
    verbs[8] = "type";
    verbs[9] = "be";

    adjec[0] = "Tangy";
    adjec[1] = "Sour";
    adjec[2] = "Smooth";
    adjec[3] = "Sticky";
    adjec[4] = "Soft";
    adjec[5] = "Black";
    adjec[6] = "Whispering";
    adjec[7] = "Resonant";
    adjec[8] = "Wide";
    adjec[9] = "Long";

    adver[0] = "Truthfully";
    adver[1] = "Endlessly";
    adver[2] = "Painfully";
    adver[3] = "Tirelessly";
    adver[4] = "Beautifully";
    adver[5] = "Uneasily";
    adver[6] = "Wickedly";
    adver[7] = "Briskly";
    adver[8] = "Now";
    adver[9] = "Last";

    String v = (verbs[new Random().nextInt(verbs.length)]);
    String a = (adjec[new Random().nextInt(adjec.length)]);
    String n = (nouns[new Random().nextInt(nouns.length)]);
    String ad = (adver[new Random().nextInt(adver.length)]);

    System.out.println("Does your " + v + " your " + a + " " + n + " " + ad );
}
```

However, the sentences do not make sense. The words should probably come in another order like:

```
System.out.println("Does your " + a + " " + n + " " + v + " " + ad );
```